# Discord.js translate bot for discord

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a bot for discord using discord.js library. everything works fine until I get response from googleapis.

what I'm trying to translate for example is : "hallo Magst du grüne Bäume" and in response I'm getting "hello do you grÃ¼ne trees". And this problem occurs for most languages.

My code:

````
'use strict';
const request = require('request');
const iso = require('iso-639-1');
// const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const querystring = require("querystring");
// var baseRequest = request.defaults({
 //   encoding: null
// })

module.exports = {
    main: function(bot, msg, settings) {
        let args = msg.content.replace(/"/g, '');
        let toLang = args.split(' ')[args.split(' ').length - 1];
        toLang = iso.getCode(toLang) == '' ? toLang : iso.getCode(toLang);
        args = args.replace((" " + args.split(' ')[args.split(' ').length - 1]), '')
        args = querystring.escape(args);
        let fromlang = 'auto';
        let gurl = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + fromlang + "&tl=" + toLang + "&dt=t&q=" + args;
        request(gurl, function(error, response, body) {
            try {
              // body = iconv.decode(body, 'utf8');
              // console.log(bodyWithCorrectEncoding)
                let translated = body.match(/^\[\[\[".+?",/)[0];
                translated = translated.substring(4, translated.length - 2);
                msg.channel.sendMessage("```\nTranslated:\n" + translated + "\n```");
            } catch (err) {
                msg.channel.sendMessage("`Input was invalid`");
            }
        });
    }
};
````

as you can see I was trying returning binary file and iconv it but without success. I know that my problem lies somewhere with encoding but I cannot work it out.

Answer (score 1):

The response from the API is not in desirable encoding. In my opinion it's better to stick with UTF-8 and for this purpose you could use [UTF8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) module. In fact i tried to encode with [UTF8](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8) - hello do you grÃ¼ne trees, and it worked.

Comment: Added &ie=UTF-8 as url parameter and it solved the issue. But will try these utf8 module tomorrow as well, thanks.